# Print human friendly Protobuf message

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I couldn't find anywhere a possibility to print a human friendly content of a Google Protobuf message.

Is there an equivalent in Python for Java's `toString()` or C++'s `DebugString()`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're using the [protobuf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/2.6.1) package, the `print` function/statement will give you a human-readable representation of the message, because of the [`__str__`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class#__str__) method :-).

Comment: Indeed, this works. However, for my particular message description, for some specific message contents, the messages are printed as empty strings, but I think this is a bug from library.

Answer (score 34):

Here's an example for read/write **human friendly** text file using `protobuf 2.0` in **python**.

```
from google.protobuf import text_format
```

read from a text file

```
f = open('a.txt', 'r')
address_book = addressbook_pb2.AddressBook() # replace with your own message
text_format.Parse(f.read(), address_book)
f.close()
```

write to a text file

```
f = open('b.txt', 'w')
f.write(text_format.MessageToString(address_book))
f.close()
```

The **c++** equivalent is:

```
bool ReadProtoFromTextFile(const std::string filename, google::protobuf::Message* proto)
{
    int fd = _open(filename.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        return false;

    google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream* input = new google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream(fd);
    bool success = google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parse(input, proto);

    delete input;
    _close(fd);
    return success;
}

bool WriteProtoToTextFile(const google::protobuf::Message& proto, const std::string filename)
{
    int fd = _open(filename.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fd == -1)
        return false;

    google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream* output = new google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream(fd);
    bool success = google::protobuf::TextFormat::Print(proto, output);

    delete output;
    _close(fd);
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Is there a ruby equivalent?

Answer (score 6):

As answered, `print` and `__str__` do work, but I wouldn't use them for anything more than debug strings.

If you're writing to something that users could see, it's better to use the [`google.protobuf.text_format`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.text_format-module) module, which has some more controls (e.g. escaping UTF8 strings or not), as well as functions for parsing text-format as protobufs.